# Wait a task to finish in Blazor WASM

Tags: blazor, task, webassembly

Please tell me:
How can I wait a task until it is finished in Blazor WASM, no matter the time it takes to complete?
My `UserInfoService.GetUserBasicInfoToListAsync()` task through an API controller gets some data from a server SQL table.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
      await UserInfoService.GetUserBasicInfoToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
//here must wait the previous task to complete

    if (UserInfoService.UserBasicInfoList.Count > 0)
    { //do some code}

}
```

Comment: What is wrong with `await UserInfoService.GetUserBasicInfoToListAsync();` and how long of a timeout are you expecting? `OnInitializedAsync()` is not ideal for a long delay because it disrupts the user flow but what trouble are you experiencing?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is something like this: I'm assuming your problem is the UI rendering before the async call is complete.  [But I may be wrong!]

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

@if (loaded)
{
    <div class="bg-dark text-white p-2 m-2">
        Rows Retrieved: @NoOfRows
    </div>
}

else
{
        <div class="alert alert-warning">Loading Records to find the number</div>
}

@code {
    private bool loaded;
    private int NoOfRows = 0;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Task Delay to emulate a slow async call into the data pipeline 
        // replace with your await
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        // await UserInfoService.GetUserBasicInfoToListAsync()
        NoOfRows = Random.Shared.Next(1, 10);
        loaded = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You assumption  was correct ! It is about the UI rendering before the async call is complete. 
But I don't see await Task.Delay(3000); as a solution... Sometimes may take more or less time to complete the task...
It must be another way to wait just until a task is complete !
Thank You !

Comment: I am using a function which is loading from a table a list for every logged user and displays the element count of that list. I don't want the displayed result to be 0...
So first I need to wait the list to be loaded from the table and after the task is finished to display the real number of the element from that list !
Can you be more specific about not using .ConfigureAwait(false); ?!
Thank You !

Comment: See my revised answer and note Henk's comment.   And `.ConfigureAwait(false)` says I don't care where you run the code after the await.  The initial code will run on the UI context thread. You want any continuation code to also run on that thread.  It's almost certainly UI code, and does care very much about where it is run!  How many threads do you think you have available to you?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to the problem

```
private bool init;

public override async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
{
    parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
    if (!init)
    {
        init = true;
        persion = await SimulateTask();
    }
    await base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can hook into when task is completed, you can also test if task is faulted or cancelled with r.IsFaulted or r.IsCanceled

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        var task = UserInfoService.GetUserBasicInfoToListAsync();

        await task.ContinueWith(r =>
        {
            if (r.IsCompleted)
            {
                var result = r.Result;

                Dispatcher.CreateDefault().InvokeAsync(() =>
                {
                    // do stuff here

                    // Refresh UI
                    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```